# Regex to Detect Zalgo

Tags: javascript, regex, string, regular-language, zalgo

I'm creating a message filtering system, that detects z͎͗ͣḁ̵̑l̉̃ͦg̐̓̒o͓̔ͥ.

My current regex is `/([^\u0009-\u02b7\u2000-\u20bf\u2122\u0308]|(?![^aeiouy])\u0308)/gm`
but this also captures emojis.

The regex should filter all w̵̢̃ë̸̩́ị̵̽r̴̺̆d̴̘̕ ̴͎́ẗ̷͕́e̷̳̅x̷̮́ṱ̸̏ ̸̜͒ḻ̵̎i̶̧͐k̸̗̈ě̸͖ ̸̥̄t̶̛̤h̸̰̔i̵̿͜ş̴̛ or t̶e̶x̴t̸ ̸l̵i̶k̷e̸ ̵t̷h̵i̷s̴, but should not capture emojis.

Comment: What do you mean by "filters"? Removes these texts, or "normalizes"?

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew Liley remove them from chat entries

Comment: Detects if any zalgo is in a string. e.g. ->
`const hasZalgo = zalgo.match(zalgoPattern);`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Here is how to test

```js
const re = /%CC%/g
const hasZalgo = txt => re.test(encodeURIComponent(txt));  

console.log(hasZalgo("w̵̢̃ë̸̩́ị̵̽r̴̺̆d̴̘̕ ̴͎́ẗ̷͕́e̷̳̅x̷̮́ṱ̸̏ ̸̜͒ḻ̵̎i̶̧͐k̸̗̈ě̸͖ ̸̥̄t̶̛̤h̸̰̔i̵̿͜ş̴̛ 222 "))
console.log(hasZalgo("Weird text like %CC% this "))
```

Here is how to convert

```js
console.log(
  decodeURIComponent(
    encodeURIComponent("w̵̢̃ë̸̩́ị̵̽r̴̺̆d̴̘̕ ̴͎́ẗ̷͕́e̷̳̅x̷̮́ṱ̸̏ ̸̜͒ḻ̵̎i̶̧͐k̸̗̈ě̸͖ ̸̥̄t̶̛̤h̸̰̔i̵̿͜ş̴̛ 222 ")
    .replace(/%CC(%[A-Z0-9]{2})+%20/g," ") // replace space
    .replace(/%CC(%[A-Z0-9]{2})+(\w)/g,"$2") // replace anything else
  )
)
```